# LibGDX - PixelBufferObject creation, binding and reading

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

How can I create a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object) and bind it as a `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` do `glReadPixels` and read the data back at a later point of time from the PBO using something like `glGetBufferSubData` in LibGDX?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I am not allowed to comment. I hope the following information is what you need, judging from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24717228/3041008) that you asked earlier:

There is a [tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html#pack) which demonstrates an example where 2 PBOs are used to "asynchronously" read & process data from the framebuffer in each render frame:
the 2 PBOs are used alternatively:

- one for reading **data of the current frame** from the framebuffer to the PBO
- one for transferring/processing the **data of the last frame** from the PBO to the CPU

You can just translate the GL calls from the tutorial to the corresponding [GL calls in libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GL30.html).

Comment: As you may have seen in my other post: I have fixed my problem. So this question is kinda answered too. Back to your answer one problem with `GL30` is that it is relatively new. I think Android 4.2 oder something like that is required.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, for PBOs you need OpenGL ES 3.0 or newer. I wonder what's actually faster :) (disregarding your requirements for compatibility)